# Need to expand a Volume but Windows10 won't let me

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

Since a few weeks back and probably some Windows Update I have a new partition on my System that is 450mb large. If I look at it it's empty. I wouldn't really mind, but every five minutes I get this popup that there's low storage on the HD.

So I tried to expand this volume, but on this one I don't have the options to expand/decrease the volume. [Actually, theres only the Help option when rightclicking.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amdtt.jpg)

All other partitins have the options

Comment: If you want to do it without having to completely reformat the drive, you will need to purchase commercial partitioning software. The cost is minimal - typically $30

Comment: partedmagic is $11-12 for a single download

Comment: Why was this marked as duplicate of a post that has nothing to do with it?

Comment: It appears to be the correct answer. I don't know WHAT OP is doing with all those partitions. They're out of space because they've got a too-small primary partition. I'd guess they're running multiple Windows installations on each HDD and this is the cause of the multiple recovery partitions.

Comment: @harrymc Because despite what it looks like, this question, is asking how to stop the low space notification.  Which of course is answered by the duplicate.

Comment: @Ramhound: Actually there are two questions here, but the title only refers to one. The duplicate is of the one that is not in the title. No matter, as this should have been closed anyway as unclear.

Answer (score 0):

It probably contains critical boot files that are hidden to prevent tampering. You need to remove the drive letter instead. That will make it disappear from File Explorer.